# Cycled list - removing all given values

Tags: c++, list

I have function which suppose to delete all given values from my cycled list. The problem is program crashes every time I try to delete values which are next to each other. For example: `list: 0,7,9,9,8` and when I want  to remove value 9 program crashes.

Function:

```
 void removeAllValue(List2W& l, int x){
        if(isEmpty(l))
            return;

        Element *temp = l.head, *del;
        int i;

        if ( l.head->value == x ){
            temp = temp->next;
            deleteHead(l, i);
        }

        do {
            if ( temp->value == x ){
                if ( l.tail == temp ) {
                    temp = temp->next;
                    deleteTail(l, i);
                    return;
                }
                del = temp;
                temp = temp->next;
                del->next->prev = del->prev;
                del->prev->next = del->next;
                delete del;
            } else {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        } while ( temp->prev != l.tail);
    }
```

Whole remaining code: https://pastebin.com/57SeC0uK

Comment: *Where* does it crash? If you use your debugger, you can find out where, and probably why as well.

Comment: It crashes on the line `while ( temp->prev != l.tail);`, but I dont know why

Comment: @zimek-atomek Did you look at the values, stored within those variables, while stepping through your code, with a debugger?

Comment: Check `temp` and make sure it is pointing to valid memory (i.e. debug and inspect that variable before it crashes).

Comment: @crashmstr Ok, now i see, but how can I repair it?

Comment: btw, the block `if ( l.head->value == x ){ ... }` is wrong. Try to delete 9 from 9,9,... list.

Comment: Maybe you need to point `temp` back to the `head`? I'm not sure because I don't know what you are planning to do.

Answer (score 0):

With dash that stands for NULL, lowercase letters for fields and uppercase letters for element pointers, we build a list with code shown via pastebin:

`h:-,t:-`

`insertHead(1)`

`h:A,t:A with A:p:-,1,n:-`

`insertHead(2)`

`h:B,t:A with A:p:B,1,n:- and B:p:A,2,n:A`

There is a symetry problem here. Why A.n remains NULL ?
It may crash soon, in a forward iteration for example.
Your focus on the consecutive values is misleading.